# 9patch background breaks after adding layouts over it

Tags: android, android-layout, background, nine-patch

I´m working on a level scene where I put a 9-patch image to the background. It seems to work fine until I add some layouts, like Viewpager over it.
It looks like this:
[image]

So the upper part, where the white edge of the blanket is, should be static and the rest should fit the screen. When I add the viewpager and the viewpagertab to the screen,it breaks the background of the layout! Why is that?

The code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="10"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:paddingTop="0dp"      
>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="9"        
    android:layout_marginTop="66dp"        
   />

<core.world.ViewPagerTabs
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"        
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"               
    />
```

Comment: btw, I marked the blanket pattern area with black pixels, so this part should be stretched and the upper part should stay static.

Comment: Try using android:padding="0dp" instead of android:paddingTop="0dp"

Comment: This helped a little, although the same problem is on the bottom and was not solved by the padding tag. I also noticed that if I put a regular image to the background, the background stayed static and only the buttons were moving when I was swiping through the screens (which is the purpose), but as soon as I add a 9-patch background, the background somehow sticks with the levels so when I swipe to another screen, the background suddenly moves with the buttons.

Comment: Yes, this is an issue with 9 patch images and backgrounds, I had to break my head before I found a way around. I am sorry, I currently cannot see the image you have put, so i won't make any further guesses. Will check it again and update unless someone else solves it :)

Comment: Are u doing this? Setting the background as 9 patch and the background of the Viewpager and its content as transparent? Also are u sure about ure 9 patch image? Check for bad patches. Sometimes that causes weird behavior.

Comment: Can you provide directly example in ZIP with layout.xml and some .9-patch?

Comment: I solved this problem using a linearLayout placed above the buttons having the upper part of the background as a background and the purple pattern being a background of the activity layout. so basically the upper part of the picture is placed over the pattern part. the background is not stuck to the buttons so the background does not move with the buttons when swiping. not the best practice i think, but works.

Comment: I don´t know what bad patches I could have had there. I marked the pattern part as flexible by black pixels and the upper part as static by no/transparent pixels.so I guess the background should stretch itself according to these rules and then if the background of the viewpagertabs and viewpager are set to transparent/null, they should just be "invisible" and the activity background should be visible instead. I can´t see any logic in the background suddenly sticking to the viewpager.